# css table sorting based on different headings in the table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to create a css table that shall be dynamic.

what i want to say is that,

let the table has 4 headings,

S.no., Name, Age, Country

now each field will have a lot of data like

1. abc, 21, usa
2. def, 24, uk
3. ghj, 51, india

now what my intention is that, this table will be displayed on a webpage and will contain just fixed data.

When a user clicks on Name, the table shall be sorted by Name, if he clicks on Age, it shall be sorted by Age smaller to larger, same for country.

Can it be done guys? If yes, then how?

Thanks in advance for all your help.

Comment: Can you explain why you want to use a css table rather than a real table, and why you think the distinction is important for this question?

Comment: @MrLister what do you mean by distinction?

Comment: The difference between a table in CSS and a real table in HTML. it shouldn't matter for the task you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @Alvaro in comment, `dataTable` is your best and easiest option. You simply need to wrap your `th` in `thead` and other rows in `tbody` and you are good to go with only single line:

```
$("#<ID_OF_YOUR_TABLE").dataTable();
```

A working example is <kbd>[here](http://jsfiddle.net/wxaXD/)</kbd>

**EDIT**:- Using in your page.

Add jQuery script to your page.

```
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
```

Add `DataTable` CSS and Script to your page.

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.4/jquery.dataTables.min.js"/>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.4/css/jquery.dataTables.css"></script>
```

Then anywhere at end of page (you may add in `head` tag but I prefer at end):

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $("#<ID_OF_YOUR_TABLE>").dataTable();
});
</script>
```

**EDIT 2** :- Hiding Footer Info

Footer info is wrapped in a div with class `dataTables_info`. So you can write the style definition for this class using `display:none` to hide it. I have updated the <kbd>[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wxaXD/1/)</kbd>.

Answer (score -3):

I think you need some JavaScript to do this (Bringing the sorted data with ajax)

Comment: this should be a comment?

Comment: I think the OP may be aware of needing Javascript (as the question was tagged Javascript). And since the data is static, once you have it in memory, you won't need AJAX to bring it in from the server again.