# css table sorting based on different headings in the table - An Issue with earlier ques asked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

this is the earlier asked question

[css table sorting based on different headings in the table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21306472/css-table-sorting-based-on-different-headings-in-the-table/21322184?noredirect=1#21322184)

and this was the accepted solution.

```
$("#<ID_OF_YOUR_TABLE").dataTable();
```

and here is the working fiddle with solution.

http://jsfiddle.net/wxaXD/

now my question is this,

how can i remove show xxx entries, search bar, Showing 1 to 3 of 3 entries and previous next, all of such shit from this? in this fiddle?

EDIT: Also how can I show them all (150 entries) on one page only.

Comment: Have you read the dataTable API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace:

```
$("#tbl1").dataTable();
```

with

```
$("#tbl1").dataTable({"bFilter": false,"bInfo": false, 'iDisplayLength': 150});
```

Checkout this [Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/wxaXD/2/)

Comment: how to hide, Show xxx entries & Previous Next?

Comment: already done earlier. It was just not working. Site had some problem.

Comment: I do not have 15 reputation else, I'd have voted you up as well. :)

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty way to hide those would be adding some css

```
.dataTables_filter, .dataTables_length,
.dataTables_info, .dataTables_paginate {
    display: none;
}
```

To display all 150 rows, you can use 'iDisplayLength' option

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('#example').dataTable( {
       "iDisplayLength": 150
  } );
})
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/5v4Rd/